# how can I can get good (or just ok) at BDD for Rails using RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, bdd

I already asked a similar question on StackOverflow, and I got [a very satisfactory answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919442/how-to-learn-tdd-with-ruby#answer-4919983). I am trying to get good at testing Ruby on Rails applications with RSpec this time and *just doing it* doesn't work as mean to getting good (at least not for me).

There are too much things I don't know:

- what is a mock?
- what is a stub?
- how to test views?

Those are only three things I don't know. And while developing an app, too often I arrive at a point where I know that I need to test something and I don't know how to write a test for it...

So my question is: how can I can get good (or just ok) at BDD for Rails using RSpec?

A couple of things to mention though:

- I hate Cucumber. It's way to verbose for my taste.
- I already followed the Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl. It taught me a lot indeed.
- I am in the process of writing my first rails application which is a Tumblr clone.
- I already bought *The RSpec Book* and I am waiting for my copy to arrive. Unfortunately it covers a lot of Cucumber.

Comment: have a look at Steak - http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/steak-because-cucumber-is-for-vegetarians/ it's basically a bunch of generators for Rspec and it's new Capybara DSL - no cucumber required and no english > ruby regex's required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a beginner I learned (still learning) rspec by looking at other people's rspecs. Find a large project(eg. https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora) with and see how other people approached the rspec .

To find everything at a single place, below given link is quite helpful :

http://kerryb.github.com/iprug-rspec-presentation/

Comment: I followed your advice and ultimately I did get better at RSpec in a very short time. I'm not good yet but it will come. I still don't know what a mock or a stub is though and I still don't know how to test views... Anyway thanks for your comment.