# Can I debug dynamically added Ruby method?

Tags: ruby, debugging, metaprogramming, rubymine

I want to store brief snippets of code in the database (following a standard signature) and "inject" them at runtime. One way would be using `eval(my_code)`. Is there some way to debug the injected code using breakpoints, etc? (I'm using Rubymine)

I'm aware I can just log to console, etc, but I'd prefer IDE-style debugging if possible.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: It appears Linuxios is right - this appears to be impossible based on my limited testing with IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

Hm. Let's analyze your question. Firstly, it does not seem to have anything to do with databases: You simply store a code block in the source form somewhere. It can be a file, or a database. Secondly, you don't want IDE-style "debugging", but [TDD-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919442). (But don't concentrate on that question now.)

What you need, is assertions about your code. That is, you need to describe what output should your code produce given some input examples. And then, you need to run that code and see whether its function matches the expectations. Furthermore, if you are not sure about the source of your snippets, [run them in a sandbox (with $SAFE = 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074915). If your code fails the expectations, raise nice errors (TypeError, or even better, your custom made exception), and then you can eg. rescue those exceptions and eg. use some default code snippets...

... but maybe I'm not actually answering the same question that you are asking. If that's the case, then let me share one link to this [sourcify gem](https://github.com/ngty/sourcify), which let's you know the source, so that you can insert a breakpoint by saying eg. require 'rdebug' in the middle of code, or can even convert code to sexps. That's all I know.

Comment: I mentioned the database as storage for code just to provide context (I didn't tag this question as a database question). I'm also aware of TDD, etc. The gem link you provided does look promising, so I'll investigate that today. Thanks!