# Ruby mathematical formula from string with 'x'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In order not to get rusty I want to refresh my knowledge of pure ruby by solving some algorithms. I can't solve a larger algorithm without solving a smaller one like the example below.

Have the function missing_digit(str) take the `str` parameter, which will be a simple mathematical formula with three numbers, a single operator `(+, -, *, or /)` and an equal sign `(=)` and return the digit that completes the equation. In one of the numbers in the equation, there will be an `x` character, and your program should determine what digit is missing. For example, if str is `"3x + 12 = 46"` then your program should output `4`.

```
Examples
Input: "4 - 2 = x"
Output: 2
Input: "1x0 * 12 = 1200"
Output: 0
```

I think I found the solution for [python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-missing-digit-x-from-the-given-expression/) but I can't find the corresponding Ruby code anywhere.

Comment: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/strscan/rdoc/StringScanner.html

Comment: @max no idea how to use it in my case

Comment: I am curious: how is Stack Overflow users writing your code for you going to help you staying current?

Answer (score 0):

Python and Ruby are quite similar, though trying to convert this without some [basic TDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919442/how-to-learn-tdd-with-ruby) would have been difficult. Here is the converted to Ruby file from your python example. I would refactor this code but the simple tests here pass, those given in your linked example.

#### string_math_x.rb

```
class StringMathX
  def self.calculate(str)
    exp = str.split()

    first_operand = exp[0]
    operator = exp[1]
    second_operand = exp[2]
    resultant = exp[-1]

    # If x is present in resultant
    if resultant[/x/]
      first_operand = first_operand.to_i
      second_operand = second_operand.to_i

      if operator == '+'
        res = first_operand + second_operand
      elsif operator == '-'
        res = first_operand - second_operand
      elsif operator == '*'
        res = first_operand * second_operand
      else
        res = first_operand / second_operand
      end
      return res
    end

    # If x in present in operands

    # If x in the first operand
    if first_operand == 'x'
      x = first_operand.to_i
      second_operand = second_operand.to_i

      if operator == '+'
        res = resultant - second_operand
      elsif operator == '-'
        res = resultant + second_operand
      elsif operator == '*'
        res = resultant / second_operand
      else
        res = resultant / second_operand
      end
    # If x is in the second operand
    else
      x = second_operand.to_i
      first_operand = first_operand.to_i
      if operator == '+'
        res = resultant-first_operand
      elsif operator == '-'
        res = first_operand - second_operand
      elsif operator == '*'
        res = resultant.to_i / first_operand.to_i
      else
        res = first_operand.to_i / resultant.to_i
      end
    end
    res = res.to_s
    k = 0
    for i in [*0..x]
      if i == x
        result = res[k]
        break
      else
        k += 1
      end
    end
    result.to_i
  end
end
```

#### ./test/test.rb

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require_relative '../lib/string_math_x'
class StringMathXTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_basic_subtration
    input = '4 - 2 = x'
    assert(StringMathX.calculate(input) == 2, 'outputs 2')
  end
  def test_whats_up_returns_doc
    input = '1x0 * 12 = 1200'
    assert(StringMathX.calculate(input) == 0, 'outputs 0')
  end
end
```

To run this you may need to `gem install minitest`

Then run `ruby test/test.rb`

Answer (score 0):

```
def findx(str)
  s = str.sub('=', '==')
  i = s.index('x')
  pre = s[0,i]
  post = s[i+1..-1]
  ('0'..'9').find { |d| eval(pre+d+post) rescue nil }&.to_i
end
```

```
findx("4 - 2 = x")        #=> 2
findx("1x0 * 12 = 1200")  #=> 0
findx("3**x = 81")        #=> 4
findx("1/x == 2.0").nil?  #=> true
```

`rescue nil` is needed in case division by zero is performed. `&` is the [safe harbor operator](https://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/). It returns `nil`, disregarding all that follows, if the part before it returns `nil`.